# Navigation View Sencha Touch 2

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I have a problem with my NavigationView in Sencha Touch 2.
When I push the 'back' button, then I can't navigate more than one window.

I navigate using view.push() and view.pop().

view.js:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.view', {
extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
alias: 'widget.View',

config: {
    id: 'nvView',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'bottom',
            layout: {
                align: 'center',
                pack: 'center',
                type: 'hbox'
            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    iconAlign: 'center',
                    iconCls: 'info',
                    iconMask: true,
                    text: 'Ayuda'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    iconAlign: 'center',
                    iconCls: 'compose',
                    iconMask: true,
                    text: 'Guardar'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    id: 'volver',
                    iconAlign: 'center',
                    iconCls: 'reply',
                    iconMask: true,
                    text: 'Volver'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'formpanel',
            title: 'View',
            html: 'View1',
            id: 'View1',
            styleHtmlContent: true,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    docked: 'bottom',
                    id: 'bView1',
                    margin: 10,
                    ui: 'forward',
                    text: 'siguiente'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
});
```

view2.js:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.View2', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
alias: 'widget.View2',

config: {
    fullscreen: true,
    html: 'View2',
    id: 'View2',
    styleHtmlContent: true,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            docked: 'bottom',
            id: 'bView2',
            margin: 10,
            ui: 'forward',
            text: 'siguiente'
        }
    ]
}
});
```

view3.js:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.View3', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
alias: 'widget.View3',

config: {
    fullscreen: true,
    html: 'View3',
    id: 'View3',
    styleHtmlContent: true,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            docked: 'bottom',
            id: 'bView3',
            margin: 10,
            ui: 'forward',
            text: 'siguiente'
        }
    ]
}
});
```

ViewController.js:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.ViewController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

config: {
    views: [
        'View'
    ],

    refs: {
        bView1: 'bView1',
        bView2: 'bView2'
    },

    control: {
        "#bView1": {
            tap: 'onView1'
        },
        "#bView2": {
            tap: 'onView2'
        }
    }
},

onView1: function(button, e, options) {
    button.up('navigationview').push({
        xtype: 'View2',
        title: 'View2'
    });
},

onView2: function(button, e, options) {
    button.up('navigationview').push({
        xtype: 'View3',
        title: 'View3'
    });
}
});
```

An example of my problem is this:
I start in view1, then I push button 'siguiente' and I go to view2. If I push button 'back' (in navigationView) I go view1, then I push button 'siguiente' and go view2, but in view2, I push button 'siguiente' I can't go view3.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Gotta give some code, otherwise I don't think anyone will try to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you using `id`, so when you initiate it the second time it'll get conflict, show warning and function not working properly. You'll be safe if you use `itemId`.

```
itemId: 'bView1' //same for other view bView2, bView3
```

To reference your `itemId` in controller, just do like this for example:

```
refs: {
    bView1: '[itemId=bView1]',
    bhView2: '[itemId=bView2]',
    bhView3: '[itemId=bView3]'
},

control: {
     bView1: {
         tap: 'onView1'
     },
     bhView2: {
         tap: 'onView2'
     },
},

onView1: function(button, e, options) {
    button.up('navigationview').push({
        xtype: 'View2',
        title: 'View2'
    });
},

onView2: function(button, e, options) {
    button.up('navigationview').push({
        xtype: 'View3',
        title: 'View3'
    });
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much, you're absolutely right. I followed your instructions and I solved my problem. :) One last question: Why you change the name to reference bView2 and bView3 by bhView2 and bhView3?

Comment: lol! that is just a typo since i play dota too much :)) but glad it helped :)