# navigation with push not working

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a problem with the navigation, my page looks like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MeinView', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',

    config: {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'formpanel',
                title: 'MyApp',
                id: 'StartAnsicht',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'list',
                        docked: 'top',
                        height: 200,
                        ui: 'round',
                        itemTpl: [
                            '<div>{titel}: {inhalt}</div>'
                        ],
                        store: 'EintragStore'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        docked: 'bottom',
                        id: 'NeuerEintrag',
                        itemId: 'mybutton1',
                        ui: 'action',
                        text: 'New'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        listeners: [
            {
                fn: 'onNeuerEintragTap',
                event: 'tap',
                delegate: '#NeuerEintrag'
            }
        ]
    },

    onNeuerEintragTap: function(button, e, eOpts) {
        this.push(Ext.create("MyApp.view.AddAnsicht", {
            title: "New Item"
        }));
    }

});
```

and:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.AddAnsicht', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

    config: {
        id: 'AddAnsicht',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                docked: 'bottom',
                id: 'NeuSubmit',
                itemId: 'mybutton',
                ui: 'confirm',
                text: 'Add'
            }
        ],
        listeners: [
            {
                fn: 'onNeuSubmitTap',
                event: 'tap',
                delegate: '#NeuSubmit'
            }
        ]
    },

    onNeuSubmitTap: function(button, e, eOpts) {
        var inhalt = Ext.getStore('EintragStore');

        inhalt.add({ inhalt: '1', titel: '2' });
        inhalt.sync();

        this.push(Ext.create("MyApp.view.MeinView"));
    }

});
```

**the problem:** when I reach the second side and click the button I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'push'
```

how to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is from `this.push(Ext.create("MyApp.view.MeinView"));`

You are doing this.push in `MyApp.view.AddAnsicht` and it is formPanel, But formPanel  didn't have push method.

That's why `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'push'` error.

You are trying to push `MyApp.view.MeinView (navigation View)` into `MyApp.view.AddAnsicht (form Panel)`, But that is wrong..

You can't push navigation view into formPanel but you can push formpanel into navigation view.

What you really want to do?

Comment: Can I add the two panals to the navigation view and then use the push?

Comment: Yes, You can add how many panels you want into navigation view using push

Comment: or how to add s.th. like this.pop() to get to the previeous view

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318814/navigation-view-sencha-touch-2) question

Comment: @gurehbgui let me know if that link didn't helped you